# android signing problem while doing auto update

Tags: android, apk, auto-update

I have created a application and released it with out signing it. also i have updated my application few times after the first release.

After few months , now would like to give a another update. if i install my application in mobile , its not getting install, its installed only after i uninstalled the existing application from the mobile.

in console its showing , "Change in application signature"

I know i made a mistake by not signing the application with private key at first time. But please  any one tell me How my default debug key has changed now.. so that i can roll back.

is there any way to solve the issue? or i should ask  my users to uninstall the app.

Thanks.

Comment: Did the debug key expired and you regenerated it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things can cause the debug key to change, such as reinstalling the SDK or building the APK from a different system.  The only way to upload a new version of your app now is to delete the old one and upload the new one, e.g. `adb uninstall com.example.appPackageName` first.